# Uniqueness typing

Tags: type-theory, types

In [Uniqueness Typing Simplified](http://www.edsko.net/pubs/ifl07-paper.pdf), when applying functions, how many times the function could be used is simply ignored

[image: APP]

, however, in [I Got Plenty o’ Nuttin’](https://personal.cis.strath.ac.uk/conor.mcbride/pub/Rig.pdf)

[image]

, the application inherit the sparsity from the one of the function, why?